# Sum involving powers and a constant term

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

Let $c$ be a positive real constant. What is the value of the sum $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{c + 4^k}$ in terms of $c$. Closed form solutions please

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(c%2B4%5Ek)+k%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: the solution is anything but pretty

Comment: Do you have some reason, Hmath, to think there is an answer in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Are you still here, Hmath?

Comment: I am. It seems, the Sum I have cannot be expressed in closed form as I was hoping. Obviously, the q-analoq psi function is way more complicated than the simple expression sum I have!